# Error while using .equals() method on multi dimensional array java

Tags: java

```
if(NewItem.itemArray[i][3].equals(itemNO))
{ 
    for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
    {
        NewItem.itemArray[i][x] = null; //Change all the values in the row to null
    }
```

The compiler throws an exception when I try to run the program. What is wrong?

The following is the exception it shows.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DeleteItem.deleteItem(DeleteItem.java:34)
    at EditItemDetails.editItem(EditItemDetails.java:25)
    at CD_Universe.editItemDetailsActions(CD_Universe.java:84)
    at CD_Universe.main(CD_Universe.java:109)
```

Comment: Post the exception trace.

Comment: Did you consider the possibility that `NewItem.itemArray[i][3]` would already be null?

Comment: Also, you have terminated the `if` statement with `;` and the block below will always be executed.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Comment: Use a line breakpoint in your editor and step through the code line by line and check the variables. Debug your code.